# How to make multilevel drop down navigation with mootools?

Tags: mootools, drop-down-menu

i m new to mootools and i want a navigation with multilevel. i dont want to use class on sub unorder lists. 
**like:**

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub1</a></li>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>menu 1 sub2 sub1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently used http://mootools.net/forge/p/moodropmenu , which was straight forward. Note: the demo uses MooTools 1.2  http://www.aryweb.nl/projects/MooDropMenu/ , but looking at the source I think it should work with 1.3 nocompat too.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: [MenuMatic](http://greengeckodesign.com/menumatic)